# prohibit redirection to login page in shiro

Tags: java, spring, shiro

How can I do to prohibit redirect on login and logout?

It should work with CORS but all what I can do is sending 200 to OPTION request

shiro.ini:

```
    <bean id="corsFormAuth" class="ru.protei.eas.auth.filter.CorsLoyalFormAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <bean id="corsRoles" class="ru.protei.eas.auth.filter.CorsLoyalRolesAuthorizationFilter"/>
    <bean id="corsLogout" class="ru.protei.eas.auth.filter.CorsShiroLogoutFilter"/>

    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
        <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/error"/>
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
            /soap/** = noSessionCreation,basicHttpFilter,roles
            /rest/notifications/*/report/* = noSessionCreation,basicHttpFilter
            /auth/login = corsFormAuth
            /auth/status = anon
            /auth/logout = corsLogout
            /rest/** = corsFormAuth
            /** = anon
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/auth/login"/>
    </bean>
```